# sqlite_prepare_v2 gives error #26(File Not A Database) even when database is opened successfully

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am trying to use sqlite3_prepare_v2() in VC++ but it is giving me error #26 which is "File is not a database." which is confusing because I have opened database successfully.

```
sqlite3 *testDb;
sqlite3_initialize();
std::string location =  uribase+"testDB.sqlite3";
auto rc = sqlite3_open_v2(location.c_str(), &testDb, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL);
if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
{
    logError(rc);
    sqlite3_close(testDb);
    sqlite3_shutdown();
    return -1;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Database opened successfully.";
}
std::string tableName = "test";

std::string strstmt = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + ";";
sqlite3_stmt *pstmt = NULL;
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(testDb, strstmt.c_str(), -1, &pstmt, NULL);
if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
{
    logError(rc);
    sqlite3_close(testDb);
    sqlite3_shutdown();
    return -1;
}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qk60S.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite will not access the file until it actually needs to. (And in any case, it would be possible for another application to corrupt the file after it has been opened.)

The problem is that this file indeed is not a database file (or encrypted).

Comment: Yes, actually I just noticed that this problem is specific to this particular database file. It's not encrypted or corrupted as I can edit and access it with SQLite Administrator(https://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/) like any other database file.

Comment: Which version of the SQLite library are you using?

Comment: I am using ver 3.21.0-1 and if it matters, I used vcpkg for installing the library.